# Correct way to make request to onedrive

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to make request to OneDrive, but so far no success. I have been able to obtain access token that I think is good because I can access informations from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`. But when I try to access `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive` I get 500 error response, this is what response object says:

```
[message:protected] => Unable to resolve template token
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 500
[file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\OneDrive\vendor\thenetworg\oauth2-azure\src\Provider\Azure.php
[line:protected] => 68
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\OneDrive\vendor\league\oauth2-client\src\Provider\AbstractProvider.php
                [line] => 644
                [function] => checkResponse
                [class] => TheNetworg\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object
                            (
                                [reasonPhrase:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Internal Server Error
                                [statusCode:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 500
                                [headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Cache-Control] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => private
                                            )

                                        [Transfer-Encoding] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => chunked
                                            )

                                        [Content-Type] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => application/json
                                            )

                                        [request-id] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 7fc5c1c8-bd33-4788-bae9-5887d261c8c5
                                            )

                                        [client-request-id] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 7fc5c1c8-bd33-4788-bae9-5887d261c8c5
                                            )

                                        [x-ms-ags-diagnostic] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"003","Host":"AGSFE_IN_2","ADSiteName":"AMS"}}
                                            )

                                        [Duration] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 177.0851
                                            )

                                        [Date] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Mon, 06 Feb 2017 12:55:27 GMT
                                            )

                                    )

                                [headerNames:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
                                    (
                                        [cache-control] => Cache-Control
                                        [transfer-encoding] => Transfer-Encoding
                                        [content-type] => Content-Type
                                        [request-id] => request-id
                                        [client-request-id] => client-request-id
                                        [x-ms-ags-diagnostic] => x-ms-ags-diagnostic
                                        [duration] => Duration
                                        [date] => Date
                                    )

                                [protocol:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 1.1
                                [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
                                    (
                                        [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #79
                                        [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 237
                                        [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                                        [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                                        [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                                        [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
                                        [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [error] => Array
                                    (
                                        [code] => InternalServerError
                                        [message] => Unable to resolve template token
                                        [innerError] => Array
                                            (
                                                [request-id] => 7fc5c1c8-bd33-4788-bae9-5887d261c8c5
                                                [date] => 2017-02-06T12:55:28
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Comment: If you login to the [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer) with this account, does the `/me/drive/` call result in the same error?

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the problem was that I didn't use `v2.0` in my authorize and token URL. Now is everything working fine.

Comment: Could you post this as a response and mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I was using [thephpleague/oauth2](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) package that is recommended by official docs. Links to token and authorize URL were not to the v2.0 endpoint.